# Displaytag calling servlet with parameter value

Tags: jsp, servlets, tomcat7

I am using the display tag library in my jsp-web app to display application users like following:

```
        <display:table name="requestScope.users" pagesize="5" requestURI=""
                       export="true" sort="list" uid="one" keepStatus = "true">
            <display:column property="lastName" title="Last Name" 
                            sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
            <display:column property="firstName" title="First Name" 
                            sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
            <display:column property="userName" title="Username" 
                            sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
            <display:column property="emailAddress" title="Last Name" 
                            sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
            <display:column property="userType" title="Last Name" 
                            sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
            <display:column property="userID" title="ID"  autolink="true"  href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteUser?userID=${user.userID}"
                            sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
        </display:table>
```

i am using the last display:column element as a link to my servlet and trying to pass it the userID as a parameter.Although the servlet is accessed, the parameter is not passed when trying to use expression language! Any idea how i could get this thing to work?

Using : jdk-7u51 Windows7 Tomcat 7.0.52 Netbeans 7.4 Oracle XE11g2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diddling around and noticed a lot of people having the same issue.
Obviusly the table generated above will always pass as a parameter the first userId inside the users list.

There are two suggested solutions to generating dynamic links with displaytag as suggested here:

http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.1/example-decorator-link.jsp

Using the struts-like approach i added the 'paramId' and 'paramProperty' as follows

```
            <display:table name="${users}" pagesize="5" requestURI=""
                       export="true" sort="list" uid="one" keepStatus = "true">
            <display:column property="lastName" title="Last Name" 
                            sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
            <display:column property="firstName" title="First Name" 
                            sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
            <display:column property="userName" title="Username" 
                            sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
            <display:column property="emailAddress" title="Last Name" 
                            sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
            <display:column property="userType" title="Last Name" 
                            sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
            <display:column property="userID" title="ID"  autolink="true"  paramId="userID" paramProperty="userID" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteUser"
                            sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
                </display:table>
```

and passes the right value to the servlet. Hope this helps someone else